# Load polygons from INSPIRE XML to GeoPandas dataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, xml, inspire

The German state of [Schleswig-Holstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schleswig-Holstein) has a [geoportal](https://advmis.geodatenzentrum.de/trefferanzeige;jsessionid=F19A503EFE413DAE8DC59B246C27817B?docuuid=defbc2f3-52f0-4b0e-a196-908d678086b3&plugid=/ingrid-group:iplug-csw-dsc&docid=X4Cl9XYBWW0O27vjZYKZ), where they provide a link to their WFS endpoint:

https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities

making it possible to access the state's cadastral data. I load some parcels to QGIS canvas using this endpoint, and observe the calls made via the Network Logger:

[image]

One of the calls:

```
6701 GET https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&BBOX=599711.71880523720756173,5915094.58108168374747038,600677.40076130512170494,5916482.59453260432928801,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)
```

I am attempting to recreate what QGIS does using GeoPandas: make this call, convert response to Polygons. I try:

```
import fiona
fiona.supported_drivers["NAS"] = "raw"

import geopandas as gpd
url = "https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&BBOX=599711.71880523720756173,5915094.58108168374747038,600677.40076130512170494,5916482.59453260432928801,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)"
df = gpd.read_file(url)
```

The resulting dataframe `df` does not however contain `POLYGON`s, only `POINT`s:

[image]

I can download the response manually:

```
URL="https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&BBOX=599711.71880523720756173,5915094.58108168374747038,600677.40076130512170494,5916482.59453260432928801,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)"
curl $URL -o inspire.xml
```

[image]

**How can I make GeoPandas load the parcel polygons, instead of the reference points, into the dataframe?**

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432318/reading-inspire-xml-with-geopandas) is a similar question, where the [accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/432320/191643) relies on `ogrinfo`. I try `ogrinfo inspire.xml`, get:

```
ERROR 1: No schema information loaded
INFO: Open of `inspire.xml'
      using driver `NAS' successful.
1: CadastralParcel (Point)
2: ALKIS_beziehungen (None)
```

i.e. even `ogrinfo` does not seem to see the Polygons. They are clearly there (see screenshot of XML in browser above), but something is wrong with the schema, I believe.

---

Apparently this does not happen for everyone, as pointed out in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448654/191643). In my environment, `fiona.__version__` returns `1.8.21`, `gpd.__version__` returns `0.11.1`.

Tried the same code in Google Colab (after a `!pip3 install geopandas`), it works. There, `fiona.__version__` returns `1.8.22`, `gpd.__version__` returns `0.12.2` .

Most probably my problem is due to old GeoPandas or Fiona packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your problem, when I run your script, I get polygons:

```
import fiona
fiona.supported_drivers["NAS"] = "raw"
import geopandas as gpd
url = "https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREDOWNLOAD_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&BBOX=599711.71880523720756173,5915094.58108168374747038,600677.40076130512170494,5916482.59453260432928801,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)"
df = gpd.read_file(url)
print(df.geometry.head())
0    POLYGON ((599690.313 5915268.949, 599721.202 5...
1    POLYGON ((597116.805 5916472.623, 597248.259 5...
2    POLYGON ((600516.724 5915145.596, 600554.597 5...
3    MULTIPOLYGON (((600598.558 5915149.776, 600599...
4    POLYGON ((600510.934 5915180.078, 600512.871 5...
```

Comment: Oh ok, that's strange. What fiona and geopandas versions are you using? I appended my question to contain version info.

Comment: Apparently, if  `fiona.__version__` is `1.8.22` and `gpd.__version__`  is `0.12.2`, problem is solved.